Error when compiling Chromium on an M2 Macbook Air
So i was trying to compile Chromium on MacOS Sonoma with an M2 chip using autoninja and on [50994/61229] CXX obj/third_party/blink/renderer/bindings/core/v8/v8/v8_async_iterator_readable_stream.o it suddenly failed. The error log is extremely long but they are all about unsafe buffer access.
/Users/me/chromium/src/out/Default/../../base/containers/span.h:901:27: error: unsafe buffer access [-Werror,-Wunsafe-buffer-usage]
901 |     return UNSAFE_BUFFERS(data()[idx]);

I never actually modified the code so it's pretty weird.
I tried around 5 more times playing around with my args.gn file but nothing worked. This is my args.gn file right now by the way:
target_cpu = "arm64"
is_debug = false
is_component_build = true
symbol_level = 0

Please help

You should report this as a bug to the Chromium project. You can disable this warning by adding -Wno-unsafe-buffer-usage to your compile flags.

The UNSAFE_BUFFERS macro is meant to bypass the warning. Looks like that macro doesn't work for your compiler.

@Botje this doesn't work with autoninja

Doesn't work how? What did you try?

@Botje I put the flag after the command like this: sudo caffeinate autoninja -C out/Default chrome --Wno-unsafe-buffer-usage

Please don't try random shit and expect it to work. Ninja has no idea what to do with a C++ compiler flag. See this question

@Botje I checked it out but it doesn't work even when I change it for macos

Just try running export CFLAGS="-w" and export CXXFLAGS="-w" before compiling. Or find another way to disable treating warning as errors. Since strictly speaking those are not errors and just warnings and since your compiler options force compiler to treat warnings as errors.

the same problem

Looks like you are trying to build the master branch? The master branch mostly contains nightly builds. You should checkout a stable version and use tags to do so

To add or modify compiler flags, you typically need to use the correct configuration name in the args.gn file. To disable treating warnings as errors, you can use the following parameter:
treat_warnings_as_errors = false

This should globally disable the behavior of treating warnings as errors.
